# Conjugate Prior for correlation matrix

Tags: bayesian, correlation, conjugate-prior

Suppose x is normally distributed with unknown mean and covariance matrix.   Is there a set of conjugate priors for the mean and correlation matrix.   I know that for covariance matrices one can use inverse Wishart distribution as priors, but what about a correlation matrix?

Comment: Knowing the correlation matrix is equal to $R$ doesn't fully specify the distribution, since there are any number of scalings consistent with that correlation.  Is there a particular factorization of the covariance you have in mind, ie, $X \sim$Normal$(\mu, RD)$, for $D$ a diagonal matrix giving variances and $R$ positive definite matrix giving correlations?

Comment: If you let conjugacy go (because we have [more] efficient sampling algorithms these days), you can use the LKJ distribution, which is a distribution of correlation matrices.

Comment: I was about to name the [LKJ prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/304684) as well...