# What priors are typically used for the correlation parameter in a bivariate normal?

Tags: bayesian, prior, multivariate-normal-distribution

The [Bivariate normal distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) contains a correlation parameter. I want to implement an MCMC sampler to sample from the posterior distribution of the parameters of the bivariate normal distribution. I have already selected the priors for the mean and variance parameters. However, I was not sure how to choose the prior for $\rho\in(-1,1)$, the correlation parameter.

Are there any standard choices such as the Jeffreys prior or other noninformative priors? If so, what are they?

Comment: See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304684/why-lkjcorr-is-a-good-prior-for-correlation-matrix Obviously, this is a little simpler, when you just have a bivariate normal rather than more dimensions.

Comment: @Björn Very interesting. Too bad they do not give the prior on $\rho$ explicitly.

Comment: This [master thesis](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/handle/11250/2786134) considers a large number of priors for $\rho$.

Comment: @JarleTufto Perfect. I will accept it as an answer if you post it as such.

Comment: @Priorian "Link-only" answers are discouraged, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2487/77222, so the above comment will have to do for now.

Comment: @JarleTufto You could add a screenshot of the list of priors in page 32, but I respect your choice. So, no accepted answer for this question. Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia has a [handy table of conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution)

Comment: Have you considered representing $\rho$ with the Fisher transformation?  Because it will be approximately Normally distributed, you could use a standard conjugate prior.

Comment: @JarleTufto, "link-only" answers are discouraged unless there is context and there is no potential chance of link rot. While I agree with you, if you wish, you can briefly provide the context as well as any summary along with the archived link (which won't die) as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) is the conjugate prior to the inverse of the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution (it as a distribution over positive semi-definite matrices).
So instead of using separate priors for the variance and correlation, you can use it as a prior for the entire (inverse of) covariance matrix.

Comment: In the link you can find the marginal distributions of the matrix elements in the bivariate case - from that you can get an expression for $\rho$ as a (complicated) function of $\chi^2$ and normal random variables. I doubt however if this is useful in practice, and I'm not familiar with other useful priors for $\rho$.